# Skip foreach-frame when missing content

Tags: beamer

I automatically generate slides with foreach:

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,200} {%
  \begin{frame}{Slide with jpeg number \n}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{FileA_\n.jpg}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{FileB_\n.jpg}
  \end{frame}%
}
```

The .jpg's  come from another source, and sometimes a few of them are missing which causes the whole pdf-generation to break: "Package pdftex.def Error.File 'FileB_17.jpg' not found".

If any of the two .jpg dont exist, I would like that the slide it belongs to will be skipped but that the compilation continues with the rest of the slides. How can I program that in LaTex?

I work in RStudio with knitr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\IfFileExists` conditional within the loop

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe} %<-- For dummy images
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {a,...,e,a,b} {%
\IfFileExists{example-image-\n.jpg}{
  \begin{frame}{Slide with prefix \n}
    \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-\n}
  \end{frame}%
}{}
}
\end{document}
```

In the `mwe` package there are only a,b,c example images so the loop skips d,e images.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about missing the frame but you can avoid the error with

```
\IfFileExists{FileA_\n.jpg}}
{\includegraphics{FileA_\n.jpg}}}
{\typeout{missing: FileA_\n.jpg}}
```